# Get Response in Retrofit Android

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I'm new to learning ROS and retrofit. Can anyone help me or point out why its causing me this error, basically I want to get the name and status under the hardware json. I'm not sure if my error is coming from my POJO model.

Comment: You should post the full error logcat in stead of just 2 lines of it

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen that is the only error shown in my logcat . other errors is regarding about the running system of my device

Comment: Can you try to rename you models? `Object` is an already defined name in java so it can cause wrong import.

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen I've tried this already but still no luck.

Comment: I think that error is from this command `Log.e(" mainAction", "  hardware"+ response.body().getHardware().toString());`. It's not a real error.

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen ok so what am i supposed to do. how am i going to data bind my textview to my pojo model

Comment: You should put a debugger break at this line `                textviewhardware.setText(response.body().getHardware().toString());` to check if you response contain some data

Comment: And `hardware` is an array of objects, so that `toString` can't convert it to string directly. You have to override `toString` method or concat its values to generate a string.

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen how do i do that overriding tostring method. like i said I'm a beginner in android.

Comment: Can you provide the text that you want to display from the json to text view?

Comment: its the part of the json data under the hardware which displays the name and status

Comment: I know, but I need the real value to make the example clearer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> E/ mainAction:   response com.nera.rosbridgeclient.messages.robot_msgs.ObjectList@cea25bf
>     hardware[Lcom.nera.rosbridgeclient.messages.robot_msgs.Object;@7ec748c

This is not an `Error/Exception`, it's your `Log message`.

`Log.e(" mainAction", "  hardware"+ response.body().getHardware().toString());`

The above line generates that `error logs`.

**Cause:**

> response.body().getHardware()`

The above line will `return` you an `array` of `Hardware`. Means an `instance/object` of a `hardware array`.

So when you use `toString()` to an `instance/object` like

> response.body().getHardware().toString()

It will give you the `instance` as `String`.

**Solution:**

You are getting an `Array` of `Hardware` in response. So you have to iterate it like the following.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ObjectList> call, Response<ObjectList> response) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // add this line

       for(int i=0; i<response.body().getHardware().length; i++){
           Log.e(" mainAction", "  hardware"+ response.body().getHardware()[i].name);

           sb.append(response.body().getHardware()[i].name)); // here we append each hardware name to our string builder.
           sb.append(" "); // here we append a space separator after every hardware name, you can use whatever you want(like: newline[\n] or coma[,]).
       }
       textviewhardware.setText(sb.toString()); // now textview will show every hardware name.
}
```

Comment: what if i want to show them all in one code instead of declaring it one by one . in this line of code: textviewhardware.setText(response.body().getHardware()[0].name);

Comment: @YenBico see my updated answer(the last section means solution section). Don't forget to upvote if this answer helps you. `Happy Coding`.

Answer (score 0):

`In your`ObjectList`, create a getter to get string from hardware array:

```
public String getHardwareString() {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<hardware.length; i++) {
        Object item = hardware[i];
        result += item.name
    }
    return result;
}
```

Change the `result` concatenation corresponding with your requirement.

In your fragment:

```
textviewhardware.setText(response.body().getHardwareString());
```